# Relative blocks are not considering top positioning in a div

Tags: html, css

I have created a button with border-bottom of 4px. While hovering the button , I'm reducing the border-bottom-width as 0px and adding top of 4px to avoid affecting other elements below the button.

But the items below the button are moving while i'm hovering the button. Because, the blocks after the button are not considering the 4px top. So, It not looks good. How to overcome this problem..

```
.btn{
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #30d589;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1b8454;
}

.btn:hover{
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    top: 4px;
}
```

I have updated my code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mhGt/)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use `margin-bottom`, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5mhGt/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this css:

```
.btn{
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #30d589;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1b8454;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    margin-right: 100%;
}

.btn:hover{
    margin-top: 4px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/5mhGt/2/

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5mhGt/5/.

The easiest way to resolve your problem is to make the border transparent:

```
.btn:hover {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

You don't have to mess with another properties like `margin-bottom` or so. If you decide to change the border width in the future you won't have to have this margin always in mind.

Comment: making the border transparent will not give the transition effect while hovering.

Anyway , the solution is http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/5mhGt/2/

Thank you..

Comment: It will, as I understood your question. I thought you wanted the button to keep its height.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the border color and keep the text from jittering while animating the :hover state, try wrapping your button(s) in a relatively positioned container.

Then, update your css:

```
.btn-wrapper {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
}

.btn{
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
padding: 30px;
background-color: #30d589;
cursor: pointer;
border-bottom: 4px solid #1b8454;
display: inline-block;
transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover{
top: 12px;
border: 0px;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BpL2A/